# Python: using a method with parameters as property

Tags: python, properties

I'm trying to create some class properties from a single getter/setter-method pair that both take an optional argument. I've gotten it to work, but the code looks rather ugly and unreadable, so I was wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Here's what I currently have:

```py
class Test:

    def __init__(self, *x):
        self._x = list(x)

    def get_val(self, i=0):
        return self._x[i]

    def set_val(self, val, i=0):
        self._x[i] = val

    first = property(get_val, set_val)
    second = property(lambda t: t.get_val(1), lambda t, val: t.set_val(val, 1))
    third = property(lambda t: t.get_val(2), lambda t, val: t.set_val(val, 2))

t = Test('one', True, 3.14, 34)
t.get_val()   #'one'
t.first       #'one'
t.first = 8 
t.first       #8
t.get_val(1)  #True 
t.second      #True
t.second = [41]
t.second      #[41] 
t.get_val(2)  #3.14
t.third       #3.14
```

Is there a way to make the `property` function calls (`second = ...` and `third = ...`) more readable? Or is there a better way of doing this alltogether?

PS - this is a contrived example. In reality, `get_val` and `set_val` are more complex and I don't want to repeat their code.